# Eclipse jface tableviewer - changing celleditor at runtime

Tags: eclipse, jface, tablecelleditor, tableviewer

I am using a Table Viewer with cell editors... one is a ComboxBox and the other one is a textcell editor... At runtime based on the selection in the combo box i want to change the other cell editor to either a texteditor or  combobox... How can this be achieved??

Answer (score 2):

When you make selection in one comobox editor, you update the underlying model element with the selection in combobox editor. You get the same element in below method `getCellEditor(Object element)`. Depending on state of the element, you should either return `TextCellEditor` or `ComboBoxCellEditor`

```
org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport

org.eclipse.jface.viewers.EditingSupport.getCellEditor(Object element)
```

you find lot of help online about how to use `EditingSupport` on `TableViewer/TreeViewer`